# If $\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y+\sin^{-1}z = \pi$, then $x\sqrt{1-x^2} + y\sqrt{1-y^2} +z\sqrt{1-z^2} = 2xyz$.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y+\sin^{-1}z = \pi$, prove that 
>   $$x\sqrt{1-x^2} + y\sqrt{1-y^2} +z\sqrt{1-z^2} = 2xyz$$

I tried rewriting $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. I got 
$$z=x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
I further tried simplifying this term, but I just couldn't get the desired result.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Posts which are just a problem pasted in don't get a very good reception.  You'll get better answers if you include the work you've done on the problem and where you got stuck.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you stuck somewhere? If you don't show your work/thoughts, the question will be downvoted/closed.

Comment: I take it you know the compound angle formula. You may want to try and write $x=\sin\alpha, y=\sin\beta, z=\sin\gamma$. Can you try to express $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Have you tried spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\sin^{-1}x=A,\sin^{-1}y=B,\sin^{-1}z=C$$and $A+B+C=\pi$

It is enough to prove that $$\sin2A+\sin2B+\sin2C=4\sin A\sin B\sin C$$
Let us take $LHS$$$\implies2\sin(A+B)\cos(A-B)+2\sin C\cos C$$$$=2\sin C\cos(A-B)+2\sin C\cos C$$$$=2\sin C[\cos(A-B)+\cos C]$$$$=2\sin C[\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)]$$$$=2\sin C\ 2\sin B \ \sin A$$$$=4\sin A\sin B\sin C$$$$x\sqrt{1-x^2}+y\sqrt{1-y^2}+z\sqrt{1-z^2}=2\sin A\sin B\sin C=2xyz$$

Comment: Very nice approach. I too thought the same but ended up doing a silly mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof**.$\blacktriangleleft$ Let $A = \arcsin(x), B = \arcsin(y), C = \arcsin(z)$, then $A,B,C \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, thus $\cos(A), \cos(B), \cos(C) \geqslant 0$. Therefore we are requested to prove 
$$
\sin(A)\cos(A) + \sin(B)\cos(B) + \sin(C) \cos(C) = 2\sin(A) \sin(B) \sin(C)\quad [A + B + C = \pi].
$$
Now calculate:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm {LHS} &= \sin(A)\cos(A) + \sin(B)\cos(B) - \sin(A+B) \cos(A+B)  \\
&= \frac 12 (\sin(2A) + \sin(2B)) - \sin(A+B) \cos(A+B)\\
&= \sin(A+B) \cos(A-B) - \sin(A+B) \cos(A+B)\\
&= \sin(A+B) (\cos(A-B) - \cos(A+B))\\
&= 2\sin(C)\sin(A) \sin(B) = \mathrm {RHS}.
\end{align*}
Hence the equation. $\blacktriangleright$

Answer (score 0):

Good start. Indeed, on the one hand:
$$\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y+\sin^{-1}z = \pi \iff \\
\sin^{-1}x=\pi-(\sin^{-1}y+\sin^{-1}z) \iff \\
\sin (\sin^{-1}x)=\sin(\sin^{-1}y+\sin^{-1}z) \iff \\
x=y\cos(\sin^{-1}z)+z\cos (\sin^{-1}y) =y\sqrt{1-z^2}+z\sqrt{1-y^2}.$$
Similarly:
$$y=x\sqrt{1-z^2}+z\sqrt{1-x^2};\\
z=x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}.$$
Multiply the three equations by $\sqrt{1-x^2},\sqrt{1-y^2},\sqrt{1-z^2}$, respectively, and add up:
$$x\sqrt{1-x^2}+y\sqrt{1-y^2}+z\sqrt{1-z^2}=\\
2\left(\color{blue}{x\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-z^2)}+y\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-z^2)}+z\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}}\right)$$
On the other hand:
$$\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y+\sin^{-1}z = \pi \iff \\
\sin{(\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y+\sin^{-1}z)}=0 \iff \\
\sin{(\sin^{-1}x)}\cdot \cos{(\sin^{-1}y+\sin^{-1}z)}\color{red}+\\
\cos{(\sin^{-1}x)}\cdot \sin{(\sin^{-1}y+\sin^{-1}z)}=0 \iff \\
x\cdot (\cos{(\sin^{-1}y)}\cos{(\sin^{-1}z)}-\sin{(\sin^{-1}y)}\sin{(\sin^{-1}z)})\color{red}+\\
\sqrt{1-x^2}\cdot (y\cos{(\sin^{-1}z)}+z\cos{(\sin^{-1}y)})=0 \iff \\
x\cdot (\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-z^2)}-yz)\color{red}+\sqrt{1-x^2}\cdot (y\sqrt{1-z^2}+z\sqrt{1-y^2})=0 \iff \\
xyz=\color{blue}{x\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-z^2)}+y\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-z^2)}+z\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}}.$$